# OPENQUERY DELETE WHERE IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to delete records from local person table where employee status in remote employee table is terminated. Trying something like the following but cannot get the open query syntax correct:

```
DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE ID IN 
OPENQUERY(LSVR1,'SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_STATUS=''T'' AND TERMINATION_DATE<SYSDATE-365')
```

I get

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'openquery'."

Comment: Try `Delete From Person Where ID IN (Select * From OPENQUERY(LSVR1,'SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_STATUS=''T'' AND TERMINATION_DATE<SYSDATE-365') )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `IN (SELECT ... FROM OPENQUERY() alias)`:

```
DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE ID IN (
SELECT ID 
FROM OPENQUERY(LSVR1,
'SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEE_STATUS=''T'' AND TERMINATION_DATE<SYSDATE-365'
) sub);
```